# Is there a similar manpage for LaTeX packages/template?

Tags: packages, texlive, documentation, ubuntu

In Unix like systems, there are always manpages for the packages installed.When I'm using latex, I have to use some templates or packages. But I'm not familiar with the usage of some package.For example, `pifont` provides me with wonderful special symbols, however I would not bother to try all numbers using such like `\ding{43}` to find what it'll output. And there seems not so many cheatsheets when I try Google. It is always said that RTFM and STFW are two good ways for learning. But how for LaTeX learning?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have a full TeXLive system, almost every package comes with documentation that is accessible via `texdoc`. Try

```
texdoc <package-name>
```

Where `<package-name>` is simply the name of the package, excluding `.sty` or `.cls`.

and if that fails to find anything, try

```
texdoc -s <package-name>
```

which will show alternatives to choose from.

Comment: But it seems only works for some packages,the others cannot be got again. BTW,some packages just provide the *sty* file which I don't want to read :(

Comment: Can you give some examples of ones that don't work?  I've rarely encountered problems with most packages.

Comment: I just tried **texdoc pifont.sty**,and it provides me the source file;while **texdoc xcolor** provides me the pdf documentation for xcolor.It doesn't work for **texdoc pifont**.

Comment: `texdoc pifont` brings up the PDF documentation for `psnfss2e`, section 7 of which documents `pifont`.  In general, when you search for package documentation you should *not* use `.sty` or `.cls` etc. in the search.

Comment: I don't know why,but it always outputs *Sorry, no documentation found for pifont.*when I use `texdoc pifont`. But `texdoc psnfss2e` does work for me.Would you please tell me what's happening?

Comment: pifont is merely a series of access methods to the zapf dingbats font.  there's a description of this in the psnfss2e docs, including a font table for zapf dingbats.  "somebody" ought to add an alias so that texdoc pifont brings up psnfss2e docs; i have mailed the texdoc maintainers list.

Comment: oops -- i was wrong; texdoc pifont does the right thing (what version of tex live are you using? -- there's a lot of development of the texdoc system going on.)  in general, you are right -- there are more un*x (or linux) man pages than there are *tex package docs (plain tex is particularly bad).  but un*x has been going since the 60s, whereas people seem to have assumed everyone knew what was going on in tex, until some time like the mid-90s; the big push for documentation seems to have started with latex 2e.  no excuse for the situation, but it's a simple fact.

Comment: Also note that if you use AUCTeX you can access texdoc via `C-c ?`.

Comment: I guess you're using TeX Live 2009 (on Debian or Ubuntu maybe?). According to my tests, texdoc from TL09 doesn't find anything for pifont, with TL10 it finds psnfss2e.pdf but only in 2nd position, and with TL11 it does the right thing. Unfortunately, upgrading just texdoc is not that easy. However, you may want to install TL 2011 for the many updates (obviously not just texdoc).

Comment: By the way, as the maintainer of texdoc, I'm taking the occasion to emphasize that problem reports as simple as "texdoc <some-package> is not working (with texdoc version and TL version)" are highly appreciated (preferably on the texdoc list, (no need to subscribe)). I really need this input to improve the results since I can't possibly check every package myself. (No need to report pifont of course, wasteofspace kindly did, and it's already fixed anyway.)